# Migration of SharePoint from VM to host machine

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

would like to get your advice in the below:

Existing Setup : SharePoint 2010 + SQL database on the same server installed on the host.

Created a new virtual machine and installed SharePoint 2013 on virtual machine, but the database is made to point to the same old in the host machine.

Advice me the best practice to achieve the below:

We are not using SharePoint 2010 anymore and I would like to get the SharePoint 2013 from the VM to the host. The database is already in the host.

Thanks and Regards,
Alex

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]

Answer (score 0):

Since your database is already on the host, I would suggest reinstalling the SharePoint 2013 on the host.
If you had the SP 2013 and the SQL both in the VM you could try doing a complete backup of the VM Windows and restore on the host, but its up to you if you want to reinstall the SQL Server on the host.

Regards,
Sergiu.